# SPFastDeploy problem to deploy in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2017

Since a time ago I have a problem when I try to deploy a page of sharepoint online add-in on VS2017 with SPFastDeploy (extension). 
When I try to use SPFastDeploy, VS console show me the next error: " `The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.` "

[image]